# How to remove space from container

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a container on my landing page and it makes white space. I want it full screen. I try to make the top and right 0px, but the right still edge.
[This is what looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etQe4.png)

[And this is what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSzA6.png)

The code

```
<section class="zerra-porto">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col align-self-center">
            <h1 class="mb-4">
              Hi, My Name is <br />
              Sumnit Parfit
            </h1>
            <p>A Front End Developer</p>
            <a href="#" role="button" class="btn btn-primary">Get to know</a>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <img src="/images/foto.png" alt="" class="landing-pic" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

```css
.zerra-porto .landing-pic {
 position: relative;
 right: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using container-fluid instead of container to cover the full width space?

Answer (score 1):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you. Based on your question, we have understood that you need your content inside the container but you want your banner `image` outside the `container`, for that, we have made modifications in your HTML structure and positioned the Image in right as per your required screenshot.

Please refer to this link: https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/zgcydft1/